# Definition of a certain matrix

Tags: terminology, definition

I remember I came across matrix of the form

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

There is a name for it but I can't remember. Does anyone know the name of the matrix of this form?

Comment: Search on Jordan.

Comment: Yup, that is the one. Thanks.

Comment: May be [Jordan block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix) (though usually the ones are on upper diagonal), lower [triangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix), upper [Hessenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix) (with imagination!), [tridiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix) (with a zero upper diagonal) or [bidiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidiagonal_matrix). Also a [nonnegative matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_matrix), or simply a [square matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_matrix) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called the **Jordan Block** .

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
\lambda & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda & 1  & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda & 1\\
0 & 0 &  0 & 0 & \lambda
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: You lazy man! ;-)

Comment: Actually i dont know how to use this Mathjax =P